# Before_save not running rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

**Converting JSON of Signature-Pad to Paperclip Image Rails**

Hi got this rails 4 app that you can sig the form and save a img. Im using signaturePad.js for this Im following a [tutorial](http://makandracards.com/makandra/14379-capturing-signatures-on-a-touch-device?page=30&switch_to=cards) for convertin it to a img.
I got the sig form working and it past data but get error with Paperclip

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError 

No handler found for "[{\"lx\":157,\"ly\":81,\"mx\":157,\"my\":80},{\"lx\":157,\"ly\":79,\"mx\":157,\"my\":81},{\"lx\":158,\"ly\":79,\"mx\":157,\"my\":79},{\"lx\":158,\"ly\":77,\"mx\":158,\"my\":79},{\"lx\":159,\"ly\":76,\"mx\":158,\"my\":77},{\"lx\":164,\"ly\":70,\"mx\":159,\"my\":76},{\"lx\":169,\"ly\":66,\"mx\":164,\"my\":70},{\"lx\":171,\"ly\":64,\"mx\":169,\"my\":66},{\"lx\":171,\"ly\":63,\"mx\":171,\"my\":64},{\"lx\":171,\"ly\":64,\"mx\":171,\"my\":63},
```

For some reason is not running the callback to make the png
.
 I have google this for some months and nothing any help. Thank you
this what a go so far.

SignaturePad.rb

```
    before_save :generate_image
    has_attached_file :image # options ...

          private

  def signature_present
    if signature.size <= 2
      errors.add(:signature, :blank)
    end
  end

  def generate_image
    instructions = JSON.parse(signature).map { |h| "line #{h['mx'].to_i},#{h['my'].to_i} #{h['lx'].to_i},#{h['ly'].to_i}" } * ' '
    image = StringIO.new
    Open3.popen3("convert -size #{WIDTH}x#{HEIGHT} xc:transparent -stroke blue -draw @- PNG:-") do |input, output, error|
      input.puts instructions
      input.close
      image.puts(output.read)
    end
    self.image = image
  end
end
```

my view

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "sigPad", :action => "signature", }, :method => "post", :class => "sigPad") do %>
   <a href="#draw-it">Firma</a>
 <a href="#clear">Borrar</a>
  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="pad" width="390" height="110"></canvas>
    <input id:"signature" type="hidden" name="signature" class="output" value="output">
  </div>
<%= submit_tag("Guardar") %>
<%end%>
```

Js

```
      $(function() {
    $('.sigPad')
    .signaturePad({
      drawOnly: true,
      validateFields: false,
      lineTop:80
    })

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip is probably trying to handle it before the before_save is called. Might be able to get it to work with a before_validate. Otherwise you could refactor that code out into a separate class, and do it in the controller when you pass the parameters from the request to the model.

Comment: the before_validation its not working. can you give me example of how to refactor it for the controller. if you can. Im blind on this one and can get it to work. Thanks

Comment: I was thinking you might have to move the method around, but maybe not. Give it a try in your controller create action like so: http://pastie.org/9396355